# Two columns of autowrapped text

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to lay out several (for example, two) labels (textviews) as columns. The texts can be longer altogether than one screen line and may not contain line breaks, so they need to be formatted (wrapped) to fit the screen width.

I can arrange labels as columns if they are shorter altogether than a screen line. I can wrap a text to fit the screen if there’s only one column. But if the texts are longer and there are more than one column, I cannot achieve what I want, because the first column always fills the whole screen width.

I tried to do this via xml-markup. I tried a lot of markups using LinearLayout, TableLayout and RelativeLayout. All didn’t work. Maybe, I didn’t use them properly.

I can imagine the ways using code to manually calculate views’ widths, but haven’t tried. Any solution is welcome, but using markup only are preffered.